# Scraping a website to download all documents on it with BeautifulSoup throws IOError

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi, I would like to download all the files that are published on the following website (https://www.nationalgrid.com/uk/electricity/market-and-operational-data/data-explorer) via a Python, Julia or whatever language script. It used to be a *http* website where **BeautifulSoup** was working fine; it is now a *https* website on my code is unfortunately not working anymore.

All the files I desire to download are in a *'a'* tag and are of class *'download'*. Hence the line in the code that is not working is the following:

```
fileDownloader.retrieve(document_url, "forecasted-demand-files/"+document_name)
```

which raises the following error:

```
raise IOError, ('http error', errcode, errmsg, headers)
IOError: ('http error', 403, 'Forbidden', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x104f79e60>)
```

After some research on the net, I have not been able to find any  information on how I could scrap the document on an *https* website, would anyone have a suggestion?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Julien

```
import requests
import urllib
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.nationalgrid.com/uk/electricity/market-and-
operational-data/data-explorer")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

fileDownloader = urllib.URLopener()
mainLocation = "https://www.nationalgrid.com"

for document in soup.find_all('a', class_='download'):
  document_name = document["title"]
  document_url = mainLocation+document["href"]
  fileDownloader.retrieve(document_url, "files/"+document_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the issue is that you should pass the agent as a header in order the request to be fulfilled.

I don't know how to do it with `urllib` but since you are already using `requests` (which is more human friendly) you can achieve this with the following code:

```
import requests
import urllib

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.nationalgrid.com/uk/electricity/market-and-operational-data/data-explorer")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


mainLocation = "http://www2.nationalgrid.com"
header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}

for a_link in soup.find_all('a', class_='download'):
    document_name = a_link["title"]
    document_url = mainLocation + a_link["href"]
    print('Getting file: {}'.format(document_url))
    page = requests.get(document_url, headers=header)
    file_to_store = a_link.get('href').split('/')[-1]
    with open('files/' + file_to_store, 'w') as f_out:
        f_out.write(page.content)
```

Only with a small hack to retrieve the file name from the link.

Comment: Thank you that has solved my problem! I just put the wrong main location, which should be: mainLocation = "https://www.nationalgrid.com"

Answer (score 1):

It's not a https issue, it's just that the page you're trying to scrape has some file access restricted. It's good practice to handle exceptions when you expect them. In this case all of the file links may be broken or not accessible.

Try handling the exception like this:

```
import requests
import urllib
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.nationalgrid.com/uk/electricity/market-and-operational-data/data-explorer")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

fileDownloader = urllib.URLopener()
mainLocation = "https://www.nationalgrid.com"

for document in soup.find_all('a', class_='download'):

    document_name = document["title"]
    document_url = mainLocation+document["href"]
    try:
        fileDownloader.retrieve(document_url, "forecasted-demand-files/"+document_name)
    except IOError as e:
        print('failed to download: {}'.format(document_url))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be this the issue, because with requests instead of urllib works fine. May the correct approch was to pass some headers values in the request in order to work

Comment: When I tested this there was no difference between requests and urllib, both got 200 for .csv files that are being scraped. Ran a test with Integrity (a link checker for mac) and nothing there throws 403. My best guess is that the scraper got detected and cut off. Adding a conditional time.sleep to span out requests for smaller files in time would possibly fix this issue.